# How to clone spatial repository to django project

Tags: django, git, maven

I am new to django project and github.

I am trying to deploy a django project in my local system. From the documentation they asked me to clone spatial repository.

How can clone with spatial repositry?

I have already installed neo4j.

From where  I have to do cloning.Project root directory or core project?

Comment: 'spatial'? Are you talking about gis? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/

Comment: I am using neo4j graph database.It needs spatial.How can I clone spatial repository to my project??

Comment: Would adding https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial be enough?

Comment: I am a biginer .I think that  is enough.What else can you suggest.I am waiting for your suggestion..

Comment: I don't know django well enough to help. But reading the doc of https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial should help here.

Comment: My doubt is that do I have to clone with project root or django core project??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you can clone repository using git command

> git clone https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial.git

it will download the spatial files in your current path